# What fraction of a sphere's volume lies within a cone?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, cones

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a collection of $n$ (not necessarily independent) unit vectors which we will label $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ for convenience. The *cone* $K_B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ associated to $B$ is the non-negative linear span of $B$, i.e., $$K_B = \lbrace r_1v_1 + r_2v_2 + \ldots + r_nv_n~|~r_j \geq 0 \rbrace. $$ Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ denote the unit $(n-1)$-sphere defined as usual by $$\mathbb{S}^n = \lbrace v \in \mathbb{R}^n ~|~ \|v\| = 1\rbrace.$$

**Question:**

> Is there a nice formula known for the ratio $$\angle B = \frac{\text{Vol}(K_B\cap\mathbb{S}^n)}{\text{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^n)}?$$

Where $\text{Vol}$ refers to $(n-1)$ dimensional volume and nice means "directly involving the coordinates of the vectors in $B$"? The motivation comes from the trivial case $n=2$: when $B = \lbrace v_1, v_2\rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then the fraction of the unit circle's perimeter lying within the cone spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ can immediately be recovered from the inner product (which of course directly involves coordinates):
$$ \angle B = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cos^{-1}(v_1\cdot v_2).$$

I assume this is an extremely well-studied problem, but all my google searches so far have only yielded high school trigonometry so I am obviously missing some keywords. All help is appreciated!

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7470/is-there-a-neat-formula-for-the-volume-of-a-tetrahedron-on-the-surface-of-s3

Answer (score 3):

In principle, one can compute the volume of a spherical polyhedron by first dividing it into simplices (e.g. by [barycentric subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision)), and then computing the sum of the volumes of the simplices.

Inductive formulae for volumes of spherical simplices go back to [Schlafli](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=34587); see also [Peschl](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=79775).

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in KvanTTT's question on math.stackexchange: [Solid angle between vectors in n-dimensional space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202261/37427), see Ribando's paper:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00454-006-1253-4.pdf

There seems to be no closed formula, but rather a Taylor series expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are formulas for 2D and 3D dimensional cases in my question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/solid-angle-between-vectors-in-n-dimensional-space) through the arctan and I still can not generalize it on 4D and higher dimensions.