# Area of spherical polygons in high dimensions

Tags: convex-polytopes

Given 4 points on $S^3$. If we look at the spherical polygon formed on $S^3$, is there a formula for the 3-dimensional Hausdorff measure for it?

E.g.: When I tried to set up a spherical coordinate for the following 4 points, it's not clear to me what is the domain of the spherical angles: $\vec{0}$, $\vec{e_1}$, $\vec{e_2}$, $\vec{e_2}$, $(0,0,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$.

How about higher dimensions? Thanks!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7470/is-there-a-neat-formula-for-the-volume-of-a-tetrahedron-on-the-surface-of-s3

Comment: For higher dimensions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102793/what-fraction-of-a-spheres-volume-lies-within-a-cone