# What is the area of the piece of an $n$-sphere within a given angle of a vector?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Let $x$ be the unit vector $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $A(\theta)$ be the subset of $\mathcal{S}^{n-1}$ whose angle to $x$ is less than $\theta$, i.e. 
$$ A(\theta) = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2 = 1 \; \text{and} \; y_1 > \cos(\theta) \right\} . $$
I'd like to know the area of $A(\theta)$.  The closest I've been able to find is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102793/what-fraction-of-a-spheres-volume-lies-within-a-cone).

I can translate this into a question about multivariate Gaussians, and from thence get a double integral, but it's ugly, so I'm wondering if there's a simple formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is

> [the volume of a ball in spherical geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Hyperspherical_cap)